# How to fix a nullpoint exception across classes that you can't use get/set methods with?

Tags: java, class, graphics, nullpointerexception, 2d

### So I need my graphics variables created in StaticGUI to be used in Update... get/set methods are out, it's running on two different threads, im clueless...

EDIT: Also, is there a better way to do this than with Canvas?

Main class:

```
package sanity;

public class Client {

    int X = 1024;
    int Y = 680;
    StaticGUI gui;

    public void launch() {
        gui = new StaticGUI();
        gui.draw();



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client game = new Client();
        game.launch();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Update());
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Class with the graphics variables:

```
package sanity;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class StaticGUI extends Client {

    JFrame mainWin;
    Canvas UI;
    BufferStrategy Buffer;
    Graphics g;
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public StaticGUI() {
        mainWin = new JFrame("Game");
        UI = new Canvas();
    }

    void draw() {
        mainWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWin.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        UI.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        UI.setBounds(0, 0, X, Y);
        UI.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainWin.add(UI);
        mainWin.pack();
        mainWin.setResizable(false);
        mainWin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainWin.setVisible(true);
        UI.createBufferStrategy(2);
        Buffer = UI.getBufferStrategy();
        g = Buffer.getDrawGraphics();
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    }
}
```

Class in which i need them:

```
package sanity;

import java.awt.*;

public class Update extends StaticGUI implements Runnable {

    public Update() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(X + "," + Y);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, X, Y);
        g.dispose();
        Buffer.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: In which of the lines above do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: g2d.setColor(Color.black); - The Update Class, line 13

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you create a Client instance (called "game"), and call its launch() method, that initiates a draw() on that instance, and that later call will initialise its g2d member. Later you create an *other* instance of Client (with new Update()), and that tries to access to the g2d member of this later instance. That member is not initilised here. The two instances are different, and they don't share the values of members (the g2d is not static either).
Either you make that member static (which is generally a bad practice), or you should call draw() on the second Client as well.

Comment: I guess i'll put draw(), in the Update constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, I think you call `g2d.setColor(Color.black);` before g2d has been initialized. I believe you are missing to call `StaticGUI`'s `draw()` before that. I know you call Client's draw() inside lauch(), but you call it for Client, not for `StaticGUI` nor `Update` where the new implementation for `draw()` is used. Then, I am not sure but I suppose
    `System.out.println(X + "," + Y);

        draw();

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);`
    would solve the problem as it should call StaticGUI's draw(). (Correct me if I am wrong! :))

Comment: This method contains a non-negligible amount of overhead by calling draw with each run. I would put the g2d assignment in the `StaticGUI` constructor.

Comment: It works but I sorta wanted to keep draw() being run in the main thread, im wondering if I could use static variables to have them passed to Update? Or is that bad implementation?

Comment: @jma127, Yeah, that would be nice, but it still gives null due to g not being inistalized... Put g there, error from buffer, put it up, peer error...